# Using parameters.xml in Visual Studio Online Releases

Tags: tfsbuild, azure-devops

I'm trying to set up releases for Azure Website in Visual Studio Online. Unfortunately, I'm unable to set web.config parameters with parameters.xml via this.

As far as I've seen, there is being used powershell script Publish-AzureWebsiteProject which doesn't support parameters.xml transformations.

Is there any way to do this? I don't want to store production connection strings inside my code.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Some more details:

I've a website project with web.config as following:

```
<appSettings>
     <add key="SampleSetting" value="ABC" />
</appSettings>`
```

Then I've parameters.xml file with following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<parameters>
  <parameter name="SampleSetting" description="This is sample setting" defaultvalue="DEFAULT" tags="">
    <parameterentry kind="XmlFile" scope="\\web.config$" match="/configuration/appSettings/add[@key='SampleSetting']/@value">
    </parameterentry>
  </parameter>
</parameters>
```

And I've tried to set "Additional Arguments" as:

`-SampleSetting "$(SampleSetting)"`

And set in configuration tab "SampleSetting" as "FGH".

When I'm running release, I'm receiving following error:

`##[error]A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'SampleSetting'.`

The command that is being run to deploy azure website is:

```
 Publish-AzureWebsiteProject -Name "sheeplapublishertests" -Package        "C:\a\31c60136a\SampleWebAppReleaseBuild\SampleWebAppBuild\SampleWebApp\obj\Debug\Package\SampleWebApp.zip" -SampleSetting "FGH"
```

Comment: Actually, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn722468.aspx states (in Example 5) that one can provide there dynamic parameters. But how this can be done?

Comment: I just tried with Parameters.xml, the value in web.config is updated successfully after the website is deployed to Azure. Is there any error message displayed when you use Parameters.xml to set the value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Additional Arguments field to pass the [dynamic parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn722468.aspx) which will override the ones that are there in Web.Config.

Lets suppose that you want to override 'DefaultConnection' field with a connection string.

Save the connection string as a secure string in the *Configuration* section of your Release Definition. You can tick the little lock symbol on the right to mark a configuration variable as secure.

[image]

Then in the Additional Arguments section of Azure Web App Deployment, you can specify `-DefaultConnection $(DefaultConnection)`.

[image]

You can pass multiple parameters in Additional Arguments field.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I've already tried this and it didn't work. Please check my edited question for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can also store your product connection string in Azure. After this, you just need to place a dummy string in your web.config file. Azure will overwrite the connection string automatically. Check [this instruction](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/windows-azure-web-sites-how-application-strings-and-connection-strings-work/) for details.

Comment: Actually, there is message in build logs as following:

`2015-12-03T14:46:38.2155549Z          Adding declared parameter 'SampleSetting'.`. I guess this should work :/

Comment: In addition - I need such solution to work with cloud services as well - I hoped that automatic builds and releases will solve this. It appears, it's not working :/

Comment: Unfortunately, there is an error as the one provided in my question - `##[error]A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'SampleSetting'.` :/ I will try to dig further to find what wrong am I doing. Do you have any link that may help? Thank you!

Comment: @AdamSobaniec The error message even displays without -SampleSetting "$(SampleSetting)" argument specified?

Comment: Yes - everything works fine, and I'm seeing default value of param when  I visit my website (it reads it from web.config)...

Comment: I have to add - in the artifacts created by the build, inside zip package, I can see parameters.xml file with following content:

    <parameter name="SampleSetting" description="This is sample setting" defaultValue="DEFAULT">
    <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope="\\web.config$" match="/configuration/appSettings/add[@key='SampleSetting']/@value" />                     </parameter>

Comment: You may want to check the value in deployed web.config from Kudu services: https://<your azure webapp name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/. Select "Debug Control", it will allow you to check all the web app files in the displayed page.

Comment: Thanks - it perfectly added SampleSetting to the web.config with default value "DEFAULT"... Anyway, it still doesn't allow me to override this value. Parameters.xml looks fine as well.

Comment: Do you mean the value in web.config is replaced with the value in Parameters.xml after deployment, however you still cannot override the value via argument "-SampleSetting "$(SampleSetting)""?

Comment: Yes - exactly. Inside web.config value for "SampleSetting" is "ABC". After deployment, value is "DEFAULT" as I set it in parameters.xml. But when I try to override the value I'm receiving "A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'SampleSetting'"

Comment: I just try to deploy the website on my local PC with "Publish-AzureWebsiteProject" command and get the same result. It seems that there is some issue with this feature. As in the first line of the webpage, it indicates that "[This topic is pre-release documentation and is subject to change in future releases. Blank topics are included as placeholders.]". You may need to wait for a new release to try this feature. For now, I would recommend you to store the appsettings values in Azure.